# Short story called "The Itchy Teeth"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

About 30-40 years ago, I read an unsettling story called "The Itchy Teeth". Here's how I remember it:

There is a boy whose teeth itch. His mother is irritated by the constant sound of her son scratching at them with his fingernails.

The boy wants to stop irritating his mother, so he works with a chemistry set and creates a powder. When he puts the powder on his teeth, they stop itching ... but he becomes very small.

He shows the effects to his mother. In the last paragraph of the story, his mother sees how small he is, and puts her foot down on top of him.

I'd like to reread this disturbing short story. Google searches for "short story the itchy teeth" just come up with medical diagnoses of gum disease.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You might be able to improve your question by going through the [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) in case it helps you remember any additional details you can [edit] into the question.

Comment: Wow.  Sounds Russian.

Comment: Why are people voting to close this one?

Comment: @closevoters This is certainly a science fiction or fantasy story, with the shrinking.

Comment: That's hilarious. I'm LQTM still. 
There was a Theodore Sturgeon story about someone who smiles and shows big teeth so much that his rather dumb friend says, "Hey, was your mother a piano or something?" Turns out he's an alien who smiles when he is in psychic pain from being around idiot jerks.
*Definitely* not the story asked about, just the only other one about teeth that i know of. 
And I'm still laughing.

Comment: are you sure this is fiction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"The Itchy Tooth" by Jack C. Shuffler

Excerpts from [Evergreen Review, Volume 12](https://books.google.bg/books?id=j_5BAQAAIAAJ)

> They immediately began to make fun of him, calling him such names as
>   "Blotty" and "Itchy Tooth." His fat little hand felt the cool surface
>   of the small glass tube in his pocket. He took it out of his pocket,
>   tipped the tube, and poured a small amount of powder on his tongue. He
>   shrunk to the magnificent height of six inches.

[...]

> Her thoughts were interrupted by the grating noise that she had come
>   to recognize as a tooth being scratched. She felt like screaming.